# How can i add objects to the parent\top level of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add objects to an array so they list as this desired structure:

```
myobject1: Object:
    ItemInside: Object
myobject2: Object
    ItemInside: Object
myobject3: Object
    ItemInside: Object
myobject4: Object
    ItemInside: Object
```

but they're being added as:

```
0: Object
    myobject1: Object
        ItemInside: Object
1: Object
    myobject2: Object
        ItemInside: Object
2: Object
    myobject3: Object
        ItemInside: Object
3: Object
    myobject4: Object
        ItemInside: Object
```

This is the code used for the 2nd array:

```
var myarr = [];
$.each(returnedData, function (index, value) {

    var field = {};
    field[value.Name] = {
         display: value.DisplayName,
         cssClass: value.FieldType,    
    };
    myarr.push(field);
});
```

My array contains everything i want without error, just in the wrong structure.

An example of my current structure is here:

[image]

I'm basically just trying to add the "myobjects" to the parent, but instead they're being added to their own parent object. How can I add them so they appear as in the desired structure?

Comment: declare `var field = {};`  outside `.each`

Comment: What differs "myobject" from "Object"? Rather than showing the structure using arbitrary names for them, can you give an example of what one item in the array should look like?

Comment: The names aren't arbitrary, this is exactly as displayed in javascript object explorers such as google chrome's dev tools

Comment: why the downvote? An unhelpful downvote is what puts people off posting questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is that the top level array is actually an object with `myobject1` … `myobject4` are keys. In that case, this should work:

```
var root = {};
$.each(returnedData, function (index, value) {
    root[value.Name] = {
         display: value.DisplayName,
         cssClass: value.FieldType,    
    };
});
```